# jwplayer wont skip videos to specific time

Tags: video, jwplayer, skip

I have tried JWplayer 5, 6 and also flowplayer they all had the same problem. This is my video Page: http://video.vipserial.in//watch.php?vid=a3f1fc4e4 I have used PHP Melody to publish my videos.
Everything is fine, but when the video starts to play it can't be skipped to other minutes.

Comment: FWIW, the Longtail support forums are usually pretty responsive: http://support.jwplayer.com/

Comment: you mean no one here can help me?

Comment: No, not at all. But it's not a bad idea to cross post there. I've had weird JW Player issues in the past and some of them turned out to be actual bugs in the players itself - I didn't do anything wrong but the software was broken. Posting in their forums let them know about the issue and they were able to fix it in a later release.

Comment: You are using Flash, you need to enable pseudo streaming on your web server in order to be able to seek ahead - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430518-pseudo-streaming-in-flash

Comment: hi tnx for your answer!. how can i install this module in IIS7? iam using windows server 2008 r2... i have problem in some steps of instruction.

Comment: You should probably post a new question and tag it with "iis-7" and "video-streaming." A properly-encoded MP4 displayed with HTML5 instead of Flash supports seeking without any server-side modification needed. So you might want to think about using JW6.11 and feeding it an MP4 (H.264, with the moov atom at the beginning of the file).

Comment: This is the module - http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Internet-Information-Services-IIS7-Version2